# include .dat file in externalized pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, externalize

I'm writing my PhD manuscript and I've got a lots of figures. What I want is:

- use externalized tikz as the graphs are saved as .dat and there's a lots,
- store the externalized files in an explicit directory,
- be able to set the tikz figures size easily,
- be able to switch to `\includegraphics` with generated pdf (because I put it in my lab sharelatex which does not support shell-escape).

My answers are:

- use tikz/pgfplots externalization library,
- set the file name using `\tikzsetnextfilename`,
- set the image width using the `tikzscale`package,
- make my own `\includetikz` which looks like the following (inside the preamble).

```
% Tikz & co
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

% Tikz libraries
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

% Externalized tikz
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzexternaldisable

% Command to include and controll the tikz figure size
%
% Use it as \includetikz[width=0.2\textwidth]{/path/to/file}{myfile}
% with /path/to/file/myfile.tikz being a file.
%
\def\usepdf{}
\newcommand{\includetikz}[3][]{%
    % Get file extension
    \filename@parse{#2/#3}
    %
    % Check if tikz should be built or not.
    \ifx\usepdf\empty
        % Enable externalization.
        \tikzexternalenable
        % Set next file name.
        \tikzsetnextfilename{#2/build/\filename@base}
        % Include graphics
        \includegraphics[#1]{#2/\filename@base.tikz}
        % Disable externalization.
        \tikzexternaldisable
    \else
      \includegraphics[#1]{#2/build/\filename@base.pdf}
    \fi
}

\usepackage{style/tikz}
```

This command is used inside the file as

```
\def\path{img/chapitre2}
\includetikz[width=0.8\textwidth, height=0.4\textwidth]{\path}{eels_spectra.tex}
```

with `eels_spectra.tikz`as:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[]
        \addplot [] table [x=eV, y=loc3] {\path/data/eels_spectra.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Last, the .dat file is like

```
eV loc1 loc2 loc3
463.57605489759953 1168.0 1127.0 1146.0
463.8996794786981 1292.0 1038.0 1285.0
464.22330405979665 1289.0 979.0 1155.0
464.5469286408952 1339.0 1088.0 1229.0
...
```

I've noticed that **there were no problem in case the text inside the .dat were put inside the `\addplot`command**, but with `\path/data/eels_spectra.dat`, the pdflatex command gives me:

```
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-o
n-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "img/chapitre2/build/eels_spectra" "\de
f\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' ========
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
system returned with code 256

! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "img/chapitre2/build/eels_spectra" "\def\t
ikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' did NOT result in a usable output file '
img/chapitre2/build/eels_spectra' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Plea
se verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -
shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or
 maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'img/chapitre2
/build/eels_spectra.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.


See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.47 \end{tikzpicture}

?
```

and the job log writes:

```
Package pdftex.def Info: img/chapitre2/eels_spectra_haadf.png  used on input li
ne 86.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 193.47581pt x 107.86781pt.
(./img/chapitre2/eels_spectra.tikz
PGFPlots: reading {/home/etienne/ownCloud/Manuscrit/eels_spectra.dat}
) (./img/chapitre2/eels_spectra.tikz
PGFPlots: reading {/home/etienne/ownCloud/Manuscrit/eels_spectra.dat}
) (./img/chapitre2/eels_spectra.tikz
PGFPlots: reading {/home/etienne/ownCloud/Manuscrit/eels_spectra.dat}
) (./img/chapitre2/eels_spectra.tikz
\openout4 = `img/chapitre2/build/eels_spectra.dpth'.

PGFPlots: reading {/home/etienne/ownCloud/Manuscrit/eels_spectra.dat}
! Argument of \path has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.35 ...enne/ownCloud/Manuscrit/eels_spectra.dat};

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 54569 strings out of 492167
 1263128 string characters out of 6123477
 2177993 words of memory out of 5000000
 57937 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 590919 words of font info for 79 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 89i,20n,125p,10125b,2476s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

How can I import the `.dat`file in that case ? It's so heavy to import the .dat inside the .tikz !!!

### EDIT

I've forgotten to mention that the .dat file were correctly imported if the `\tikzsetnextfilename{#2/build/\filename@base}`were removed in the definition of `\includetikz`. I.e. defining the job name makes the .dat import crash !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, Well, Well ... Nobody was inspired by my question.

Here is the answer I found.

It sounds like `\tikzsetnextfilename` is not made to specify a directory. One should either use the prefix. In other words:

- Use the prefix to specify the directory where the job should be saved,
- Use `\tikzsetnextfilename` to specify the job name.

What I made is to define the following command

```
\newcommand{\setpath}[1]{% Input like /path/to/file
    \graphicspath{{#1/}}% sets /path/to/file/
    \def\tikzpath{#1}% sets /path/to/file
}
```

Hence, at every begining of chapter, I use `\setpath{/path/to/chapter/images}`to define the current path to images (png as tikz).

The command includetikz` became:

```
\def\usepdf{}
\def\tikzpath{}
\newcommand{\includetikz}[2][]{%
    % Get file extension
    \filename@parse{\tikzpath/#2}
    %
    % Check if tikz should be built or not.
    \ifx\usepdf\empty
        % Enable externalization.
        \tikzexternalenable
        % Set file prefix
        \tikzsetexternalprefix{\tikzpath/build/}
        % Set next file name.
        \tikzsetnextfilename{\filename@base}
        % Include graphics
        \includegraphics[#1]{\tikzpath/\filename@base.tikz}
        % Disable externalization.
        \tikzexternaldisable
    \else
        \includegraphics[#1]{\tikzpath/build/\filename@base.pdf}
    \fi
}
```

and I now include tikz images inside each chapter with `\includetikz[width=0.8\textwidth]{my_image.tikz}`.

And managing the externalization with prefixes solves my .dat file importation problem.